# select date from SQL column with datetime format

Tags: mysql

[image: Format allowed for user to input] [image: Format stored in SQL]

Im trying to select from SQL a column with datetime format e.g. `2017-12-31 12:01:12`, but I only need to select date only e.g. `2017-12-31` based on what date the user input in a form and submit. The goal is to select all activities within that date.

Example: the input format in the form is `yyyy-mm-dd` only,  however in SQL, dates are stored as `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`, if the input date is `yyyy-mm-dd` format, this will be ignored for the column data is stored in this format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`.

How can I select `yyyy-mm-dd` only from the `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` in the column?

```
$mysql=("SELECT action_time FROM table WHERE action_time ='".$date."' Order by 
action_time DESC");
```

Comment: I don’t understand.  Are you saying that, if the user enters ‘2017-12-31’, you want to find all date times between 2017-12-31 00:00:00 and 2017-12-31 23:59:59?  And what if the user enters ‘2017-12-31 12:01:12’?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @Scott thank you for the head up. I just edited my question. Please advice

Comment: (1) As far as I can see, your images don't really contribute anything to the question that isn't adequately explained by your words. (2) I asked you, what if the user enters ‘2017-12-31 12:01:12’?  Are you saying that your form makes that impossible? That's the sort of thing that you need to explain. (3) It's been years since I've worked with SQL, but, just as a matter of general logic, I would suggest that you consider something like `SELECT action_time FROM table WHERE action_time>=$date AND action_time<=$date+23:59:59`.

Comment: @Scott thank you for the reply. The user can only input this date format 'yyyy-mm-dd'  as mentioned in the question. The user cannot include time but date only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only the date part interests you, use [`DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date):

```sql
SELECT DATE(action_time) FROM table;
```

Note that you should always check user input, as the client side (HTML and JS) can be altered to send arbitrary data to your server. Also check out [how to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/7796750)

Comment: Thank you @LEI, I put 

SELECT action_time FROM table WHERE date(action_time)=$date_selected.

Comment: About the SQL injection - I think that the only the format to minimize sql injection is to use a <selected> on top of PDO etc,  option in every form. As possible, only username and password should be the only form that requires users to type something before $_POST or etc.

Comment: I believe you can use this clause too: `"... WHERE action_time LIKE $date_selected%"`. If you want to format the rows from within MySQL you should operate on the `SELECT`.

Comment: Oh thank you @LEI, appreciate everything....

Comment: You're welcome. I stress again that it is not a good practice to concatenate variables in SQL queries, using `PDO` to bind parameters is simple and safe. Also any front-end HTML form can be modified to send weird stuff, take care!

Comment: thank again I really appreciate it. I'm applying your advice since I'm new at this. Arigato.....!!!!!